# Encoding/decoding non-ASCII character when using Python Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, character-encoding, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have some data with non-ASCII characters. I attempted to take care of it using the following:

```
# coding=utf-8
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import sys
import re
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('latin1')
```

Though I have identified some records still giving me encoding/decoding problem. I have copied and pasted one of the problematic record (containing the name and location columns of the record) as below:

```
'EugÃ¨ne Badeau'    'E, QuÃ©bec (county/comtÃ©), Quebec, Canada'
```

Using the .decode('utf-8') adding to the exact text extraction it resolved the problem.

```
print 'EugÃ¨ne Badeau   E, QuÃ©bec (county/comtÃ©), Quebec, Canada'.decode('utf-8')
output: Eugène Badeau   E, Québec (county/comté), Quebec, Canada
```

So I try to use it to convert my pandas column:

```
df.name = df.name.str.encode('utf-8')
```

The location seems to be ok, but the name is still wrong:

```
print df.location[735]
print df.name[735]

output:
E, Québec (county/comté), Quebec, Canada
eugã¨ne badeau
```

Comment: i can't reproduce your error ... it looks like maybe the problem is that your name column has been converted to lower case?

Comment: I just tested it with different text editors, the default python IDLE seems to have no problem (don't even need to use the .encode or .decode), but sublime text 3 seems to constantly giving me the issues, which is a shame since I like this editor a lot and thought it would be something easily fixed in a setting.

Answer (score -1):

You could do apply combined with unidecode lib:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

df['name']=df['name'].apply( lambda x:  unidecode(unicode(x, encoding = "utf-8")))
df['location']=df['location'].apply( lambda x:  unidecode(unicode(x, encoding = "utf-8")))
```

;)